# Expectation of a half- multivariate normal distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, statistics, linear-transformations

[image]I want to calculate the value of an expectation over a half- normal distribution. Attached please find something that has been in my mind until now. I think that it is not correct and also I don’t know how I can get rid of dimension in the denominator.

Thank you very much in advance. [My thought](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2tjN.jpg)

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to calculate.  In the image linked to in your question, you appear to be trying to calculate $
\mathbb{E}\big(\mathbf{I}_{
\,b_k^TX\ge0}\,b_k^TX\big)\ $
where $\ \mathbf{I}_A\ $ is the indicator function of the event $\ A\ $, and $\ X\ $ is multivariate normal with mean $\ 0\ $ and covariance matrix $\ \Sigma\ $, while the question itself seems more to be asking about $\ \mathbb{E}\big(b_k^TX\,\big|\,b_k^TX\ge0\big)\ $ instead.  These aren't the same thing, so which is the one you actually want to calculate?

Comment: Hi lonza, thanks for your consideration. My question is the first argumen. I have also add another pic to be more clear what exactly I want to calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\ X\ $ is multivariate normal with zero mean and covariance matrix $\ \Sigma\ $, then $\ Z=b_k^TX\ $ is a a normal variate with zero mean and variance $\ \sigma^2=$$\,\mathbb{E}\big(b_k^TXX^Tb_k\big)=$$\,b_k^T\mathbb{E}\big(XX^T\big)b_k=$$\ b_k^T\Sigma b_k\ \ $.  Therefore
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big(\mathbf{I}_{b_k^TX\ge0}\ b_k^TX\big)&=\mathbb{E}\big(\mathbf{I}_{Z\ge0}\ Z\big)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty ze^\frac{-z^2}{2\sigma^2}dz\\
&=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-y}dy\\
&=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{b_k^T\Sigma b_k}{2\pi}}\ .
\end{align}

Comment: Dear lonza, thank you very much. I am really appreciative of your help and guidance. The point is Z is a one dimensional random variable?

Comment: Yes.  Not merely one dimensional, however, but also *normally distributed*.